# Angular 1.6 component containing directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have an existing system built extensively with directives. I'm trying to replace it slowly, bit by bit, with components.
I have a component that looks like this:

```
var GenericDataController = (function () {
    function GenericDataController() {
        this.dtoData = '';
    }
    GenericDataController.prototype.$onInit = function () {
        this.dto = angular.fromJson(this.dtoData);
    };
    return GenericDataController;
}());
var GenericData = (function () {
    function GenericData() {
        this.bindings = {
            dtoData: '@',
        };
        this.controller = GenericDataController;
        this.templateUrl = 'GenericDataTemplate';
    }
    return GenericData;
}());
App.component('generic', new GenericData());
```

**generic** takes in a json string dtoData which needs to be resolved into the dto object in the controller. Then in the template I have a bunch of old directives like this:

```
<div directive1="{{$ctrl.dto.Directive1}}"
     directive2="{{$ctrl.dto.Directive2}}">
</div>
```

When you put a breakpoint inside the directive `compile` function, you see that in `tAttrs` `{{$ctrl.dto.Directive1}}` has not been resolved yet, i.e. stays as the string
"{{$ctrl.dto.Directive1}}". Is there anyway they can be resolved in the `compile` function so it can work? I'm trying to do this because replacing everything might take a while and there is no immediate results that I can test.

Thank you :)

Edit: Actually figured out that deeper down inside `compile` you have access to `attrs` which are `tAttrs` but resolved into values... So consider this question resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Actually figured out that deeper down inside `compile` you have access to `attrs` which are `tAttrs` but resolved into values... So consider this question resolved.